# Handling confidential data in a Microsoft power app

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I've been looking into building a power apps canvas app in my organisation's account. Part of this app will include a form which I want to submit into a data source that only limited people can access.

To do this I followed a tutorial which used a Sharepoint list as the data source for the form. This works, but when I publish the app and share with specific users I find that these users must also have edit permissions on the list itself in order to submit the form. This presumably means they would be able to locate the form within SharePoint and see and edit other people's submissions.

What is the recommended way to implement confidential forms like this in a power app?

Comment: Take a look [here](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Powerapps-and-Sharepoint-Online-Permissions/m-p/850520/highlight/true#M270338). I've successfully used this method to prevent Sharepoint List URL from "leaking" to other users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to you List in SharePoint.

Take a look at [item level permission](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2019/05/sharepoint-online-set-item-level-permission-in-list.html#:%7E:text=How%20to%20enable%20item%2Dlevel%20permissions%20in%20SharePoint%20Online%3F&text=Click%20on%20%E2%80%9CAdvanced%20Settings.%E2%80%9D,can%20set%20Item%2Dlevel%20settings.) on SharePoint, I believe this is what you need

Answer (score 0):

You can connect Source SharePoint list to SharePoint designer software to hide the SharePoint list or modify the permission level.